# ErrorCollector in Jbehave story

Tags: jbehave, errorcollector

The ErrorCollector rule allows execution of a test to continue after the first problem is found (for example, to collect all the incorrect rows in a table, and report them all at once).

I try to use org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector with Jbehave story but after execution, JBehave says "All the tests passed" even though there are some failures and the ErrorCollector() collected them. JBehave should say some steps failed.

In JUnit it's ok:

```
public static class UsesErrorCollectorTwice {
  @Rule
  public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();

  @Test
  public void example() {
    String x = [..]
    collector.checkThat(x, not(containsString("a")));
    collector.checkThat(y, containsString("b"));             
  }
}
```

But in jbehave:

```
Scenario: S-1
Given check something
```

....

```
@Given("check something")
    public void checkLoggedIn() {        
        loginSteps.check_that();
    }
```

......

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;
import org.junit.Rule;
```

....

```
@Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();
```

....

```
@Step
    public void check_that() { 
        collector.checkThat("Error example", navigationMenuPanel.isUserSignedIn(), Matchers.is(false));
        collector.checkThat("User has not been logged-in yet!", navigationMenuPanel.isUserSignedIn(), Matchers.is(true));
        collector.addError(new Throwable("Shit error happen"));
        collector.checkThat("It'wrong", 1, Matchers.equalTo(3));
    }
```

This story always passed.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Whenever I use Error Collector in Jbehave, even though the step fails Jbehave says all the tests are passed. Weird one.